# Netbeans 8.2 can't deploy project to Wildfly when the RUN button is clicked

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, wildfly

I have searched the web for solutions but can't seem to find any.
Please, I am new to using Netbeans and Wildfly.

When I try to click the RUN button to deploy my project, I get the below:

```java
13:30:28,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
13:30:28,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
13:30:28,772 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 3873ms - Started 343 of 665 services (52 services failed or missing dependencies, 415 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I can't seem to figure out where the problem is coming from.
I need help, please.

**EDIT**

```java
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default (missing) dependents: [service jboss.messaging-activemq.default] 
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_23-bin_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:/CoreUat, service org.wildfly.data-source.CowrywiseDS, service org.wildfly.data-source.FlutterAlpha, service jboss.driver-demander.java:/EpinDS, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 13 more ] 
      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:10090
      service jboss.undertow.listener.https: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.https: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8543
      service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8180

14:20:44,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
14:20:44,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
14:20:44,447 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 4346ms - Started 343 of 665 services (52 services failed or missing dependencies, 415 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Have you defined your server correctly in your project ? Do you see WildFly as running in the Services window ?

Comment: @ehsavoie I can log in to my Admin console. My Wildfly server is running and I can access it on the web browser. But when I click the RUN button, it results in that error.

Comment: [1] Update your question to specify your version of Java, your version of of Wildfly and your O/S. [2] The errors _"...Address already in use /127.0.0.1:10090...Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8543...Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8180"_ suggest that you are trying to start Wildfly when it is already running. Are you absolutely 100% certain that is not the case? If Wildfly isn't already running you need to find out what is using ports 8180, 8543 and 10090 and kill those processes.

Comment: I guess NetBeans is starting WildFly properly but is trying to connect to  9990 while your management is waiting on 10090. You should configure your plugin accordingly.